# After submitting bootstrap modal form in Rails, how to show modal with errors?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, simple-form

I'm using a bootstrap modal and the Simple_form gem with Ruby on Rails. All runs fine once submitted. The problem is when when there are validation errors, the modal closes as the submit button has been pressed. The errors are only shown if the modal button is clicked once more.

I need the end-user to see the error messages once the form is submitted - I've been thinking I could use javascript to relaunch the modal if there are errors but I can't quite figure out how. Any help would be great thanks.

My modal is as follows:

```
      <%= link_to "Click here &raquo;".html_safe,
    "#myModal", data: { toggle: 'modal'}, class: "button-main", id: "button-contact" %>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Email Contact Form</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= simple_form_for @contact, url: contact_path, html: { id: "contact-form" } do |f| %>
                    <%= f.error_notification %>
            <%= f.input :name, error: 'Name is mandatory, please specify one' %>
            <%= f.input :email, label: 'Your Email' %>
                    <%= f.input :email_confirmation, label: 'Confirm your Email address' %>
                    <%= f.input :preferred_time, collection: ["Any time", "9am - 12pm Tuesday", "2pm - 6pm Tuesday", "9am - 12pm Wednesday"], selected: "Any time" %>
                    <%= f.input :subject, collection: ["New Appointment", "Request to change existing appointment", "Information", "Other"], selected: "New Appointment" %>
                        <%= f.input :message, as: :text %>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Send", 'data-disable-with' => "Sending...",  class: "submit-button", id: "modal-send" %>
                            <p class="warning">
                                Certain email providers have been known to mark our replies as spam, please be sure to check your junk mail inbox if awaiting a response
                            </p>
                <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my model:

```
  class Contact

    include ActiveModel::Model
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :name, :email, :email_confirmation, :message, :preferred_time, :subject

    validates :name,
      presence: true

    validates :email,
      presence: true, length:  { minimum: 6, maxium: 30 }, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }, confirmation: true

    validates :email_confirmation,
      presence: true, length:  { minimum: 6, maxium: 30 }, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }

    validates :message,
      presence: true,  length: { minimum: 6, maxium: 1000 }

  end
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's not the cleanest or best way to do this, but finally found a solution to load the modal again only if there are errors. Just added the following to my page with the modal.

```
<% if  @contact.errors.present?%>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
    </script>
<% end  %>
```